# Gluing copulas along a curve

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, copula

Let $C(u,v)$ be a 2-copula and $W(u,v)=\max(u+v-1,0)$. I want to glue $C$ with $W$ along the curve $u^2+v^2=1$ s.t $$D(u,v)=\begin{cases}u+v-1,& u^2+v^2\ge 1,\\ C(u,v), &u^2+v^2<1 \end{cases}$$

is a copula. Does anyone know references which deal with Copula gluing along some curve $\theta_1(u)+\theta_2(v)=1$ (s.t $\theta_1(u)+\theta_2(v)\le u+v$). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Your "glued" function must fulfill the copula conditions as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Definition) and that's all. For general $C$ the gluing construction will **not** work as the conditions are not fulfilled. For example the whole mass of $D$ will in general not integrate to one.

Comment: Maybe "coupling" is the right terminology instead of "gluing"